# Multiple ports sockets limitations?

Tags: c#, sockets

Are there some limitations in multiple port listening. My application listens hundreds of ports but it seems that after 160 ports it can't get other ports to listen ..

Comment: Why would an application need to listen to more than just a few ports? The only thing I can think of is if you were trying to detect port sniffing.

Comment: no ..my client asked this. He wanted to have 1 port for every client. I wanna to know only if this is technically possible ?

Comment: You don't need to listen on different ports, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created simple application that listened on 1000 ports using [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) and it worked fine.

So it seems, that either there is no limitation, or the limitation is more than few hundreds ports.

There is probably some problem in your code or in your setup.

Comment: I create a socket object for every port to listen..Is this the right approach ?

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to do it and it works fine for me when I try it.